# NSTask: How to get context upon conclusion since no userInfo dictionary is supplied?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstask

I'm trying to zip files using the command-line utility through NSTask.

pseudocode:

```
controller:
  init:
    register_self_as_observer_of_nstask_notifications

  startZip(file):
    file = somefileobject 
    task = "zip" with file path as argument
    task.launch

  notification_listener(notification):
    task = notification.get_object
    file = task.???
```

So how can I find out which file object the notification pertains to? I usually use the userInfo dictionary for such things, but NSTask has no such option. **From [Apple Dev](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html):  This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary.**

Thanks!

Comment: Does one controller instance spawn more than one task concurrently?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's why I need a way to associate tasks with files.

Comment: That's one of the first things I tried, but NSDictionary attempts to copy the task when it is used as a key, and NSTask does not implement NSCopying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the associated object API to attach a user info dictionary to the task instance. This would be the cleanest approach, but it cannot be used prior to the introduction of the associated object API with Mac OS X 10.6.

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary that maps from task to user info. Creating a dictionary mapping from task to user info is not as straightforward as it sounds:

- You can't just `[taskInfoDict setObject:userInfo forKey:task]` because `NSTask` does not conform to `NSCopying`, but `NSDictionary` relies on copying its keys.
- Using the process identifier wrapped as an `NSNumber` as a proxy for the task object mostly works. But process IDs can be reused, and a task doesn't get a PID till after it's been launched. The root of the problem is: You don't control the process ID; the underlying OS does.

Using the address of the task object seems to be the best solution:

```
[taskInfoDict setObject:userInfo forKey:[NSValue valueWithPointer:task]]
```

Assuming a reference-counted environment, the task object's address will be stable for its lifetime, and its lifetime is entirely under control of your application. A copying garbage collector would throw a wrench in this solution, but in that case, you could use a collection class that can handle the pointer directly (`NSMapTable`).

Comment: That's one of the first things I tried, but NSDictionary attempts to copy the task when it is used as a key, and NSTask does not implement NSCopying.

Comment: Could you use the task process ID (wrapped in an `NSNumber`) as the key?

Comment: @Alexandre: Use an `NSValue` wrapping the address of the task as the key instead of the `NSTask` object itself. And the associated object approach is unaffected by whether `NSTask` conforms to `NSCopying` or not.

Comment: I ended up going with Wevah's suggestion (see above) of using the NSTask's pid as the dictionary key and it worked beautifully. Can you see any reason not to?

Comment: Process IDs can be reused, and a task does not receive a process ID till it has been launched. The address of the task is fully under your application's control. (The associated object approach is the cleanest of them all, though.)

Comment: But only compatible with 10.6. :( Rather than PID, how would I use the address of the task as the dictionary key? How do I get an object that represents the task's address?

Comment: Figured it out! [NSValue valueWithPointer:file] does the trick as the dictionary key. Worked perfectly!

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer? I will move some of the content from the comments here into my actual response.

Comment: Just did. Thanks a bunch for the help Jeremy!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to associate the file URL/path to each task instance. Every object can have multiple associated objects, and each associated object has a corresponding key that is used to reference the associated object when needed.

In your controller, create a `static` variable that represents the file URL/path key:

```
static char fileURLKey;
```

When creating an `NSTask` instance, associate the corresponding file URL to that instance:

```
NSURL *fileURL = …;
NSTask *task = …;
objc_setAssociatedObject(task, &fileURLKey, fileURL, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

When the task has finished executing, get the task from the notification object and then get the file URL from the task:

```
NSTask *task = [notification object];
NSURL *fileURL = (NSURL *)objc_getAssociatedObject(task, &fileURLKey);
```

Comment: I ended up going with Wevah's suggestion (see above) of using the NSTask's pid as the dictionary key and it worked beautifully. Can you see any reason not to?

Comment: @Alex Well, I find associative references more simple and general. You ended up using a dictionary and manually managing it whereas associative references do that work for you automatically.

Comment: Alright, I will try to replace the Dict approach with your approach. Thanks!

Comment: Oh oh, just noticed this technique is 10.6 only. Still a lot of Leopard users out there. Wevah's technique seems more compatible.

Comment: @Alex Jeremy’s is the most suitable answer if you’re targeting Leopard.